# Java Servlet & MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, servlets

What's wrong with this code? It gives me "brand" = null.

```
public String getBrand(@WebParam(name = "regNr") String regNr) throws SQLException {

    String brand=null;
    Connection con;
    Statement st;
    ResultSet rs;

    String url = "jdbc:mysql://db4free.net:3606/cars";
    String user = "cars";
    String password = "";

    try {
        con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
        st = (Statement) con.createStatement();
        rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Cars WHERE nr= '" + regNr + "'");

        if (rs.next()) {
            brand=rs.getString("brand");
        }


    } catch (SQLException ex) {

    }
    return brand;
}
```

I want to display the value of brand from database. Is it a problem with connection?

Answer (score 1):

Either the query isn't returning any rows or a `SQLException` is being thrown. Add something to your catch block to discover what the exception is.

BTW: You should be calling `close()` on your `ResultSet`, `Statement` and `Connection` instances. I suggest putting those calls within a `finally` block. Additionally, your code is vulnerable to an attack called [SQL injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection). Use a `PreparedStatement` with parameters to repair this problem.

Comment: There is an exception, but I'm not sure how to repair it

Comment: What is the value of `ex->getMessage()`?

Answer (score 1):

There probably is an exception in the code but you don't see it because of the `catch` with nothing inside. Add a log of the exception inside it, to reveal the exception and see the problem.